# Merging list of objects with other object, javascript

Tags: javascript

I'll try to keep it short and sweet

I have an object with a list of objects inside of it like so :

```
myObj=
{"first" : {"test1" : [1,2,3]}
```

And I am given a new object that I need to "push" (not in the literal sense) into the value object here

So if I'm given  :

```
{"test1" : [3,4,5]}
```

It should turn into

```
{"first" : {"test1" : [3,4,5]}
```

Thats if it has the same key, if it is a new key i would just like to push it in like so

```
   given 
   {"blarg" : [6, 8, 19]}
```

would turn into

```
  {"first" : {"test1" : [1,2,3], "blarg" : [6, 8, 19]};
```

Originally I was doing something like

```
  var key = "blarg",
      vals = [6, 8, 19],
      where = "first",
      temp = {};

     temp[key] = vals;
     myObj[where] = temp;
```

However this simply overwrites the current object and does not handle the various scenarios. Thanks!

Comment: Can do this instead?  `myObj[] = temp;`

Comment: @Misunderstood A) I think that's PHP, B) myObj is an object and not an array.

Comment: That is why there was a question mark.  I was being lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var key = "blarg";
var vals = [6, 8, 19];
var where = "first";
var temp = myObj[where] || {};
temp[key] = vals;
// In case we did a first-time init of the 'where' key.
myObj[where] = temp;
```

I think all you were missing was *not* creating a new object when one of the keys (ie, "first") already existed.